# ¿Cómo cargar axios - php - vue?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, axios

Cree dos archivos php, uno con el código html y vue. 
index.php

```
<div id="main" class="container">

      <pre>
          {{ $data | json }}
      </pre>

</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var urlUsers = 'data.php';
    new Vue({
        el: '#main',
        created: function() {
            this.getUsers();
        },
        data: {
            lists: []
        },
        methods: {
            getUsers: function() {
                axios.get(urlUsers).then(response => {
                    this.lists = response.data
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Y por otro lado el archivo data.php

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
return json_encode($arr);
```

Sin embargo, no logro comunicarlos.

*Omití el cargado de todos los scripts y estilos adicionales para dejar más claro el problema*

Comment: Por favor, añade más contexto para poder ayudarte. No se entiende muy bien lo que preguntas. No veo donde llamas a `getSome`. Has probado algo?

Comment: no veo donde le indicas a Vue que tenga lista la funcion, deberías tenerla así debajo de methods created: function(){
      this.getUsers()
    },

Comment: Me parece que si la agrego después de la creación de el, tengo created, no sé si te refieras a eso.

Comment: amigo @Cragser hazle un echo a tu json en el archivo php y con eso ya debe quedar

Answer (score 2):

Te comento que en lugar de hacer un return en tu código php deberías hacer un echo; por lo siguiente

1. Echo muestra múltiples cadenas de texto impresas
2. Return devuelve el control del programa, del módulo o método invocado

Entonces debes escribir en tu archivo PHP del modo siguiente

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $arr = array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4,"e"=>5);
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

Tu archivo que contiene el código frontend, debería quedar así

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="main" class="container">

                <pre>
                    {{ $data | json }}
                </pre>


          </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var urlUsers = 'data.php';
        new Vue({
            el: '#main',
            data: {
                lists: []
            },
            created: function() {
                this.getUsers();
            },
            methods: {
                getUsers: function() {
                    axios.get(urlUsers).then(response => {
                        this.lists = response.data
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> También como notas agregué en tu PHP la cabecera de Contenet-Type para
>   indicar durante el proceso de la petición; el tipo de formato que esta
>   viajando y que en este caso es de formato JSON

Mayor referencia de Header()

http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php